# Loading Widgets Via Child Theme

Tags: php, widgets, sidebar

I'm using the very popular [Elementor](https://elementor.com/) theme to build my WordPress site, but unfortunately there is not a Widgets option when I go to Appearance in the Dashboard:

[image]

I need it in order to create a sidebar.

So this has caused me to install a Child Theme, so that I can add some code to `functions.php` in order to get the widgets option to show.

This is what I have in my `functions.php` file for the child theme:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );

function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'outWidgetsInit');

function ourWidgetsInit() {
    register_sidebar( array (
        'name' => 'Sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar1',
    ));
}
```

And this is causing errors to show at the top of the theme while developing:

[image]

Why is the code showing at the top of the screen? What should I do differently here?

Comment: That does not  look like an error, it seems to be simply printing the code you have added, so something - perhaps another plugins - is causing this issue, you might need to disable all other plugins / themes to try to resolve.

Comment: Is that your entire `functions.php` file? Or just what you added?

Comment: @TomJNowell That's the entire `functions.php` file for the child theme, yes.

Comment: And you've confirmed this issue happens everywhere that you try to do this? Not just on your specific site or local setup? There is nothing in your `functions.php`  that could do this, the problem is elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, maybe it was caching-related, but waiting a day and then adding this code at the bottom of `functions.php` solved the issue:

```
if (function_exists("register_sidebar")) {
    register_sidebar();
}
```

According to this article - see the 'How do I add the Widgets menu option'

https://elementor.com/help/hello-theme-tips/

So then the full code for my `functions.php` file within the child theme is:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );

function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'outWidgetsInit');

function ourWidgetsInit() {
    register_sidebar( array (
        'name' => 'Sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar1',
    ));
}

if (function_exists("register_sidebar")) {
    register_sidebar();
}
```